# Dynamic pie charts

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, pie-chart

Is it possible to create below type of pie charts and values create dynamically (please go through the link)?

- http://img406.imageshack.us/img406/7139/piechart.png

Answer (score 1):

Since your tags specify flex as your language, why are you not just using the built in [PieChart](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=charts_types_09.html) and set the dataProvider based on query results? Also as stated by Brad Gignac googles charts API would work as well... however if your working on some sort of intranet application and some act of god causes your connection to the outside world to break its not going to work.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into Google [Visualization](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/) and [Charts](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/) API. I have personally used the charts API and it is pretty easy to use. I would like to check out the Visualization API for a project I'm working on now - it looks pretty intriguing as it can pull data from user-defined data source.